# How to get current selected item of combobox

Tags: c#, wpf

How to get selected item of ComboBox in viewmodel. i haev used WPF combobox and Observable collection. having any property of observable collection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ICollectionView then you can use CurrentItem property to get selected item.

```
 <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeeCollection, Mode=TwoWay}" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 0):

WPF does not bind the collection directly, it creates a `CollectionView`.So you can get the default view and then get the current item.

```
System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView myCollectionView = (CollectionView)CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(collection);
object item = myCollectionView.CurrentItem;
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.collectionviewsource.getdefaultview(v=vs.110).aspx